# Isight on Ubuntu 11.10 (Macbook 4.1)

Tags: 11.10, webcam, macbook

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Macbook 4.1 and just after installing the isight firmware by following the instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleiSight everything was working fine. I got AppleUSBVideoSupport from here http://turanct.wordpress.com/2010/06/

But afterwards I installed a bunch of updates (around 300) and after rebooting Isight isn't working anymore.

I redid what is on that website above, I added the ppa sources and upgraded but no luck :( Can anyone help!?! I really need to use the webcam as my dears are abroad. Thanks a zillion

Answer (score 1):

I kept the AppleUSBVideoSupport from the MacOSX 10.5 that was installed originally in my MacBook 4.1 to use it in Ubuntu 11.10 64 bits. I followed the same instructions in the wiki, but got no video as well.

I noticed some facts:

- Changing the resolution in Cheese makes the image to appear.
- Using 'v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! videoscale' on gstreamer-properties also makes its test to work.
- Skype's webcam doesn't work at all

**But yesterday I finally got Skype working!!!**

Remember Skype is a 32 bits application, so it depends on the package ia32-libs installed.
Create a file called skype.sh with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

Make this file an executable. Open the menu-editor (alacarte) and edit the Skype entry to point to this script. Be happy!

I don't know what this library does, but it solved my problem. I haven't tested other applications, but I know we'll have to use the equivalent 64 bits library with 64 bits applications.

**UPDATE:** Just upgrade to 12.04, follow the same instructions and your iSight will work with Cheese, Skype, Empathy and Google Talk.

Comment: ia32-libs has no installation candidate for Ubuntu 12.04, according to `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`