# Macbook iSight not working

Tags: webcam, macbook

I've tried to get my iSight camera working but for some reason don't know what's wrong. I've followed the instructions on both:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleiSight

and

http://turanct.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/use-your-macs-isight-on-ubuntu/#comments

The problem is after I type in terminal sudo apt-get install isight-firmware-tools I go through as the instructions say but when I put in the AppleUSBVideoSupport file path it says that there is no file located at that path? Not sure what to do now.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

EDIT: here's the technical specs of the Macbook.

1.83 GHz MacBook (MA254LL/A)

Processor   1.83GHz Intel Core Duo

L2 Cache    2MB

System bus  667MHz

Memory  2GB of 667MHz DDR2 SDRAM (PC2-5300) on two SO-DIMMs

Hard drive  160 GB Intel Solid State Drive 320 Series(SSD SA2BW160G3H) 2.5", 3Gb/s SATA SSD160GB 5V 1A

Optical drive   Slot-loading Combo drive (DVD-ROM/CD-RW)

Graphics    Intel GMA 950 graphics processor with 64MB of DDR2 SDRAM shared with main memory1

Video camera    Built-in iSight

Display     13.3-inch (diagonal) glossy TFT widescreen display, 1280 x 800 resolution

Ports   One FireWire 400 port (8 watts); Two USB 2.0 ports (up to 480 Mbps); Mini-DVI port with support for DVI, VGA, S-video and composite video output (requires adapters, sold separately)4

Audio   Built-in stereo speakers, built-in omnidirectional microphone, combined optical digital audio input/audio line in, combined optical digital audio output/headphone out

Networking  Built-in 10/100/1000BASE-T (Gigabit)

Wireless3   Built-in 54-Mbps AirPort Extreme wireless networking (802.11g standard)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103658/isight-on-ubuntu-11-10-macbook-4-1)?

Comment: Make sure to provide us with specific hardware information to minimize complications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually just installing Tahr as we speak and after a quick Google it seems that Apple no longer use a USB camera for iSight anymore, rendering the USB firmware workaround you're trying useless. As far as I can tell there is no current workaround. I'm aware this is a **very** late response, but it may help others who come across this page.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just used the first link you provided to get mine working. I think it's all in the syntax of your command line statements. If you have the path to your files wrong than it won't work. It took me a while to work through the instructions but in the end I figured it out and it works. So any one reading this post just take note. And if you mess up you have to clean the mess up as mentioned in the link. I had to mount another on of my macbooks with a live cd to get the file needed. Moved it to a usb drive and then to my Ubuntu Studio. My paths where different than the instructions have and I had to figure that out before it worked. You have to make the script file and have it as part of the startup. They explain that but I didn't have the program installed so I had to install it to. I'm running 12.4 with latest updates FYI. It took me about a day of reading and careful testing before I had the cam working. but I'm slow lol.

Comment: Please consider adding some paragraphs to make your answer readable